# Acomodar resultados por semana y dia

Tags: sql

Buen dia, tengo esta consulta que me devuelve las ventas por dias y en semanas, pero no logro que me muestre todo en una sola linea, lo que obtengo es lo 
siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
SELECT
  (case when datepart(dw,Date)=2 then SUM([Quantity]) end) as Lunes,
(case when datepart(dw,Date)=3 then SUM([Quantity])  end) as Martes,
(case when datepart(dw,Date)=4 then SUM([Quantity])  end) as Miercoles,
(case when datepart(dw,Date)=5 then SUM([Quantity])  end) as Jueves,
(case when datepart(dw,Date)=6 then SUM([Quantity])  end) as Viernes,
(case when datepart(dw,Date)=7 then SUM([Quantity]) end) as Sabado
 FROM [MXQUEFLEX].[dbo].[tblVSM1hxh] where Area like   '%Ensamble%' and DATEPART(YYYY,Date) = '2019' and
 DATEPART(ww,Date) between '36' and '38' and Quantity > 0 
 group by DATEPART(ww,Date),Date
```

espero puedan ayudarme a que todo lo producido por semana quede en una sola fila.
GRACIAS.

Comment: Una sugerencia para tus preguntas de bases de datos: siempre indica en qué motor de BD estás trabajando y la versión del mismo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes el SUM mal acomodado. Debe estar alrededor del CASE, además de eliminar la columna date del GROUP BY.

```
SELECT
    SUM(case when datepart(dw,Date)=2 then [Quantity] end) as Lunes,
    SUM(case when datepart(dw,Date)=3 then [Quantity]  end) as Martes,
    SUM(case when datepart(dw,Date)=4 then [Quantity]  end) as Miercoles,
    SUM(case when datepart(dw,Date)=5 then [Quantity]  end) as Jueves,
    SUM(case when datepart(dw,Date)=6 then [Quantity]  end) as Viernes,
    SUM(case when datepart(dw,Date)=7 then [Quantity] end) as Sabado,
    SUM([Quantity]) AS TotalSemana
FROM  [MXQUEFLEX].[dbo].[tblVSM1hxh] 
WHERE Area like   '%Ensamble%' 
  and DATEPART(YYYY,Date) = '2019' 
  and DATEPART(ww,Date) between '36' and '38' 
  and Quantity > 0 
group by DATEPART(ww,Date);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! funcionó, y si quisiera agregar un campo mas de total por semana como podriía hacerlo?

Comment: Solo se agrega una sumatoria más sin ningún CASE como lo dejé despues de editar la respuesta.